# Paginating in Pisa (xhtml2pdf) just repeats last page

Tags: python, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I am using [Pisa](http://xhtml2pdf.appspot.com/static/pisa-en.html) to produce a PDF file with pages that follow a common format.
I am clearly doing something wrong as when I generate the PDF (either from from the command line or from the python API) I only ever see the last page repeated.

Running the Pisa on the code below, I get three pages that each say "C Wednesday", when I'd expect to see three different pages with "A Monday", "B Tuesday", "C Wednesday".

My current version of Pisa is `XHTML2PDF/pisa 3.0.33 (Build 2010-06-16)`

```
<html>
<style>
    /* 297 x 210 */
@page {
  size: a4 landscape;
  margin: 1cm;
  margin-bottom: 2.5cm;

  @frame header {
    -pdf-frame-content: headerContent;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    top : 0cm;
    margin-left: 0cm;
    margin-right: 14.5cm; 
    height: 2.5cm;
    width: 14.9cm;
  }

  @frame lhs {
    -pdf-frame-content: lhs;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    top : 4.5cm;
    margin-left: 0cm;
    margin-right: 14.5cm; 
    height: 13.5cm;
    width: 14.9cm;
  }

  @frame footer {
    -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
    color:black;
    bottom: 1cm;
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-right: 24.5cm; 
    height: 1cm;
  }

}

body {
}

#headerContent {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 200%;
}

#lhs-table {
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:600%;
}

.big {
    font-size:200%;
    font-style:italic;
}

.day {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 1.6cm;
    height: 1.3cm;
}

#footerContent {
    font-size: 200%;
}


</style>
<body>

<div>
  <div id="headerContent">
      <h1><br/>HEADER<br/></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="lhs">
      <table id="lhs-table" >
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="big"><em>A</em></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>

  <div id="footerContent">
      <span class="day" >Monday</span>
  </div>

  </div>
    <pdf:nextpage />


<div>
  <div id="headerContent">
      <h1><br/>HEADER<br/></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="lhs">
      <table id="lhs-table" >
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="big"><em>B</em></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>


  <div id="footerContent">
      <span class="day" >Tuesday</span>
  </div>

  </div>
    <pdf:nextpage />


<div>
  <div id="headerContent">
      <h1><br/>HEADER<br/></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="lhs">
      <table id="lhs-table" >
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="big"><em>C</em></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>

  <div id="footerContent">
      <span class="day" >Wednesday</span>
  </div>

  </div>
    <pdf:nextpage />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try version from Github https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf Your version is too old and unmaintained.

About your problem, is a known problem in the parser. Try to put the tag on its own line like this:

```
<div id="footer">
     <pdf:pagenumber />
</div>
```

AFTER THIRD READING:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>

 <div id="content1>
   content 1
 </div>
 <pdf:nextpage />

 <div id="content2>
     content 2
 </div>
 <pdf:nextpage />

 <div id="content3>
     content 3
 </div>
 <pdf:nextpage />

<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

From your code, you are repeating header and footer for each content. But you have defined them as header frames (automatically repeat them on each page), so the parser must be going nuts. Also you are creating another static frame for content, which shouldn't be.

So, only one header, one footer, create many contents with `<pdf:nextpage />` behind.

https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/usage.rst

Maybe I've undersrtood you wrong again, cause I don't know how are you generating this html.

Comment: I just tried the latest version from git repository as you suggested, but I am still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: Added explanation to answer.

Comment: I didn't have any luck with that approach either. You you post a simple working example?

Comment: man, sorry, I didn't understand your issue. I am about to rewrite my answer.